# count number of cases per month in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a table like the following in PowerBI.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG9Qg.png)

I want to calculate the number of cases arrived per month based on the "repair arrived date " that I have in my dataset.

I am confused with the function that I should use.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgMVB.png)

I tried the following but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: You should probably look into calendar tables to set up your evaluation context, and the use of active/inactive relationships to perform accurate counts for this sort of use-case.

Comment: How do you get the finish date? or finish status? If you can include some sample data with column names that would be helpful

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I am not sure if I can attach an excel file here.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I am not sure if I can attach an excel file here. The colums that I have imported in PowerBI are: case id, repair arrived date and repair finished date. I created 2 separate graphs that saw the number of cases that arrvied each month and the number of cases that finished each month. My problem is that I want to combine these 2 graphs. So in my uderstanding I have to create a measure that will count how many cases arrived each month and how many cases finished each month.

Comment: Then in the x-axis i will have the month and in the y-axis I will have the count of cases that arrived and the count of cases that finished per month. My issue is that I don't know how to write the DAX function in order to calculate these 2 different counts ( one count for cases arrived and one count for cases finished for each month )